# Como distribuir un .jar en mac mediante .dmg con Drag&Drop?

Tags: java, macos, drag-and-drop, jar

Necesito convertir un `.jar` en un `.app` que incluya `JRE` dentro del dentro para poder distribuir en MacOS Sierra como un archivo `.dmg` con `Drag & Drop` sin la necesidad de instalar `JDK` o `JRE` (que ya venga incluido en el `.app`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera de lograr convertir un .jar a un archivo .app (nativo de mac) con el JRE dentro y listo para ejecutar en cualquier mac y de una manera sencilla, es utilizando javapackager:
una manera simple de utilizarlo es Instalando el [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) en MacOS.

Podemos verificar la version del javapackager en terminal con el siguiente comando:
`javapackager -version`

Dará un resultado similar a:

```
Java Packager version 8.0
```

La manera de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
javapackager \
> -deploy \
> -title TituloApp \
> -name NombreApp \
> -appclass com.clase.de.tu.app \
> -native dmg \
> -outdir ~/Desktop \
> -outfile out \
> -srcfiles elJarQueDeseasConvertir.jar
```

al final tendremos (en caso de seleccionar ~/Desktop como directorio de salida) una carpeta en el escritorio llamada **bundles** donde estara el archivo `.dmg` Drag&Drop con el `.app` dentro y `JRE` integrado para ejecutar sin necesidad de instalar nada mas, solo resta modificar los logos y el fondo, lo cual es muy facil y se puede encontrar en internet el como hacerlo.

[Documentacion de Oracle acerca de javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html)